# How to randomly distribute some available data in excel (a million entries) to a group of 10 columns/rows?

Tags: excel

I have a column of "IDs" of employees (about 1million entries) and I want to distribute them randomly to new 10 rows/columns in a new excel sheet.

For instance:

```
Card ID  
  123

  132

  143

  ...
```

I want to randomly distribute this data to 10 new columns/rows (whatever is feasible) in a new excel sheet.

Comment: What have you tried already? Are you wanting to use VBA or Excel formulas?

Comment: So you have data in `A1:A1000000` and you want it randomly into approximately `B1:K100000` when a procedure is run, right?

Comment: @ashleedawg  I just want to randomly distribute it to those 10 columns and prepare an excel sheet with those 10 columns having the entries randomly. Then I'll import it to python for further use.

Comment: I'm confused - what is the difference between *`randomly distribute it to those 10 columns`* and then *`prepare an excel sheet with those 10 columns having the entries randomly`*?  Do those two sentences not mean the same thing?   Also, was the assumption in my comment above correct?

Comment: @ashleedawg yes they mean the same thing sorry to write it twice. Yes your assumption is correct. I just the want the data to be randomly placed in the new 10 columns.

Comment: Please edit your question to be more clear about expected output.

Comment: @VBV - I can slap something together.  Is it exactly a million items, and you need exactly 100,000 per output column?  ('Random" in the literal sense would be "around" 100,000 each.)

Comment: So let me elaborate a bit.

There are about 150000 entries (Sorry it wasnt a million, they are 1.5Lac). They are Card IDs of employees. In those 1.5 Lac CardID's, there are many repeated CardIDs. So I want every unique CardID to be allotted randomly to any of the 10 columns. So the number of unique ID's maybe only 1Lac or even less. Is it possible for you to do something like this?

Comment: If you want to create a permutation of a list of entries, use the `RAND()` function to put random numbers in the next column and sort that column :-)

Comment: if you want to remove duplicate entries manually, On the Data tab, click Remove Duplicates (in Data Tools group) or use ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo then use =rand() in another column and copy across into the 10 columns

Comment: Forgot to add in the above, is to sort the random number rows before copying across to the columns.

Answer (score 0):

This procedure is one of several ways you could accomplish this:

```
Sub randomColumns()

    Const inputSheet = "Sheet1" 'name of the sheet with the million values
    Const inputColumn = 1 'column # where the million values are
    Const inputStartRow = 1 'rows # of the first value
    Const outputColumns = 10 'number of columns randomize into

    Dim wsIn As Worksheet, wsOut As Worksheet
    Dim rw As Long, inValue As Variant, outCol As Long
    Set wsIn = Sheets(inputSheet) 'setup worksheets
    Set wsOut = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add 'create new worksheet
    rw = inputStartRow
    Randomize 'seed random number generator

    With wsOut
        Do
            inValue = wsIn.Cells(rw, inputColumn) 'get the value to move
            outCol = Int(Rnd() * outputColumns) + 1 'pick random column
            .Cells(Application.WorksheetFunction. _
                CountA(.Columns(outCol)) + 1, outCol) = inValue 'move value
            wsIn.Cells(rw, inputColumn) = "" 'remove value from old location
            rw = rw + 1 'next input row
        Loop While wsIn.Cells(rw, inputColumn) <> "" 'loop until blank cell
    End With
    MsgBox "Randomized " & rw - 1 & " items to worksheet '" & wsOut.Name & "'."

End Sub
```

Change the value of constant `inputSheet` to the name of the worksheet with the values. If necessary change the other constants, otherwise it will start looking for values in `A1` of `inputSheet`.

A new worksheet will be created and then each number will be placed at the bottom of the values in a randomly selected column, and then deleted from `inputSheet`.

This will continue until a blank cell is encountered on `inputSheet`.

---

### More Information:

- MSDN : [**Randomize Statement**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/randomize-statement)
- MSDN : [**Rnd() Function**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/rnd-function)
- MSDN : [**WorksheetFunction.CountA Method** (Excel/VBA)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-counta-method-excel)
- MSDN : [**Sheets.Add Method** (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/excel-vba/articles/sheets-add-method-excel)

Comment: Woah! Thank you so much for your time and effort. I'm going to try it out and update you.